# Showing that a family of functions is a Hilbert basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm doing an exercise in $H=L^2(\mathbb R^+, \mu)$, where $\mu$ is the measure with density $e^{-x}$. In the previous questions I showed that $L_n$ (the Laguerre polynomials) are orthonormal and that the functions $e^{-\alpha x}$ are in the closure of their span. The next question is this:

> Let $F$ be the set of smooth and compactly supported functions on $\mathbb R^+$. Then prove that span of the functions $e^{-nx}$ is dense in $F$ under the uniform norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$.

I think I can get this through Stone-Weierstrass, but then the final question is:

> Show that $(L_n)$ is a Hilbert basis in $H$.

I don't see what that has to do with the previous question, which was about a totally different space of functions, with a totally different norm. Is there some density result I'm not aware of that I should be using?

Comment: If $\text{span}(\{\phi_n\}_n)$ is dense in $H$, then $\text{span}(\{\phi_n\}_n)^{\perp} = \{0\}$ so that $\forall n, \langle f,\phi_n \rangle = 0 \implies f = 0$ and hence (since $\phi_n$ is an orthonormal family) $f= \sum_n \langle f,\phi_n \rangle \phi_n$

Comment: @user1952009 I don't quite follow. Your last equation is just saying $0=0$, isn't it? How can this be applied to my problem?

Comment: It was for the last question. Before that, show that $\text{span}(\{e^{-nx}\}_n)$ is dense in $F$ for the $\|.\|_\infty$ norm, then show that $\text{span}(\{e^{-nx}\}_n)$ is dense in $F$ also for the $\|.\|_H$ norm, and $F$ is clearly dense in $H$. Hence $\text{span}(\{L_n\}_n)$ is dense in $H$, and you can apply my 1st comment.

Comment: @user1952009 Okay, so what I was missing was that being dense for the $||\cdot||_\infty$ norm implies being dense for the $||\cdot||_H$ norm, and that $F$ is dense in $H$. But once we show that the span of the $L_n$ is dense in $H$, aren't we done? Is that not the definition of a Hilbert basis (since we already know they're orthonormal)?

Comment: This is my 1st comment : $\{L_n\}_n$ dense in $H$ and orthonormal means that $\forall f \in H, f = \sum_n \langle f, L_n \rangle L_n$ which is the definition of an Hilbert (orthonormal) basis

Comment: The details : since $L_n$ is orthonormal $f - \sum_n \langle f, L_n \rangle L_n$ is well-defined and orthogonal to all the $L_n$, hence it is in $\text{span}(\{L_n\})^{\perp} = \{0\}$ i.e. $f =  \sum_n \langle f, L_n \rangle L_n$

Comment: Pedantic remark: For the claim (the family is dense **in** $F $), every function from the family would have to belong to $F $. But this is clearly false. Also, do you know the stone weierstrass theorem?

Answer (score 1):

You were given that $d\mu = e^{-x}dx$. Let $y=e^{-x}$. Then
$$
     \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-nx}f(x)d\mu(x) = \int_{0}^{1}y^{n}f(-\ln y)dy.
$$
The function $f \in L^2_{\mu}[0,\infty)$ gives $g(y)=f(-\ln(y))$ in $L^2[0,1]$ because
$$
    \int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|^2e^{-x}dx=\int_{0}^{1}|f(-\ln(y))|^2dy.
$$
You can now invoke standard results for $L^2[0,1]$ to get what you want.